Google map - Using Javascript API - How to highlight disputed countries
We are a nonprofit organization who would like to highlight all the countries where we sent our donations, including countries with disputed borders, like Kosovo.
We are using the Google Maps Platform with the Javascript API.
We use the feature layer "Country" to change the style of selected countries.
Everything works fine for countries that are not disputed.
We tried to use the same pattern for disputed countries that we use for other countries but with no success. We are unable to change the style of disputed countries and we can't even listen to the mouse-over event for displaying a proper tooltip.
Is this can be done ?
Any suggestions on how we can do it using google map ?
[UPDATED]
I've been asked to add the code. Here's the simplified code example we are using, it is a mix of Vue.js and javascript ( for google map )
async showData(value) {
  this.graphData = [];

  let title = "Total donations in IUs/MGs";

  this.graphData.push(["Country", title]);
  datasource = this.datas.countriesReceivingDonations.year;

  this.graphMinValue = 1;

  this.graphMaxValue =
    datasource.length == 0
      ? null
      : datasource.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
          return prev.value > curr.value ? prev : curr;
        })?.value;
  this.graphTitle = title;

  await Promise.all(
    datasource.map(async (x) => {
      let placeId = await this.findPlaceId(x.code);
      let color = '#FF0000';

      this.graphData.push([
        { v: x.code, f: x.name, placeId: placeId, color: color },
        x.value,
      ]);
    })
  );

  this.setFeatureLayer();
},

async findPlaceId(countryCode) {
  //https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder#GeocoderRequest
  const request = {
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: countryCode,
    },
  };

  const { Geocoder } = await this.loader.importLibrary("geocoding");

  var geocoder = new Geocoder();
  var result = await geocoder.geocode(request);

  console.log(result.results[0].formatted_address);
  console.log(result);

  return result.results[0].place_id;
},

setFeatureLayer() {
  try {
    // Add a feature layer for countries.
    this.featureLayer = this.map.getFeatureLayer(
      google.maps.FeatureType.COUNTRY
    );

    // Add the event listeners for the feature layer.
    this.featureLayer.addListener("click", this.handleClick);
    this.featureLayer.addListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);

    // Map event listener.
    this.map.addListener("mousemove", () => {
      // If the map gets a mousemove, that means there are no feature layers
      // with listeners registered under the mouse, so we clear the last
      // interacted feature ids.
      if (this.lastInteractedFeatureIds?.length) {
        this.lastInteractedFeatureIds = [];
        this.featureLayer.style = this.featureLayer.style;
      }
      this.infoWindow.close();
    });

    this.featureLayer.style = (featureStyleFunctionOptions) => {
      const placeFeature = featureStyleFunctionOptions.feature;

      let fillColor;
      let strokeColor;
      let strokeOpacity;
      let strokeWeight;
      let data = this.graphData.find(
        (x) => x[0].placeId == placeFeature.placeId
      );

      if (data != undefined) {
        fillColor = data[0].color; //"#ed174d";
        strokeColor = "gray"; //"#ed174d";
        strokeOpacity = 1.0;
        strokeWeight = 1.0;
      }

      return {
        fillColor,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor,
        strokeOpacity,
        strokeWeight,
      };
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
},


Please post your code, as a minimal, reproducible example, preferably as a runnable stack snippet. It will be easier for us to help.

This is expected behavior. Check the boundaries coverage to know whether the feature is available or not. Add you own geometry / polygons for disputed territories.

@MrUpsidown, that's what we though, we wanted to prevent uploading polygons for all the disputed countries. I guess we won't have a choice and do this option.

In a way, if Google decided to not show them is exactly because... well, they are disputed, and their borders might not be clearly defined and agreed upon internationally. Maybe you could consider showing some information on your map for those countries without showing their borders.

This is what we will do, we will do a work-around. This is one downside of Google map, when a country is disputed, you can't interact with it directly, the country is disabled in the "Country" layer, so you can't color borders or even listen to "mouse-over" to display a pop-up when you over it. You need to add a custom polygon over the country to have events to triggers, like the on "mouse-over". This way, you can still display information when a user mouse-over it.
